# Any advantage to the .223 mag?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In the custom weapon menu, some weapon can get their magazine replaced by a .223 x 20 magazine. On some weapon (SVD...) it allow to have far more ammo than their base caliber, but it also appear on some assault rifle (G44), where it would make you get less ammunition.

Is there any advantage, in accuracy, damage or whatever, to use .223 caliber on a weapon like the G44?

Comment: Most of the different weapons you will research have unique components to add to your customization repertoire. Not all of them are useful, especially if you start researching a particular weapon's tree from the beginning late in the game. You can use the UN-ARC's 20-round magazine with the SVD knockoff because they are the same caliber, for example, but you will lose all of the penetration that sniper rifle rounds get, which arguably defeats the purpose of using a sniper rifle.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc exactly right, however there is an advantage to using assault rifle ammo with a sniper rifle - you can slap together a sniper assault rifle that will do much higher damage than an assault rifle firing the same rounds, and you can refill your ammo (and carry much more) from the dropped weapons of common soldiers you kill. The penetration is a good trade-off because it's still higher than what the assault rifle would give you, and the damage doesn't go down. it can be useful in some circumstances, especially close quarters where you need more punch but less spray n pray.

Comment: @jammypeach Targets aren't particularly hard to aim at for me in this game, so hitting a soldier in an area that will critically wound or kill them isn't a problem. The penetration is much more important, in my opinion. The scavenging ammo part is important, but I don't use my sniper rifle -that- much. I do wish that the game had a few missions where you "go loud," sort of like the Kojima rescue mission in Ground Zeroes. As it is, the heavy weaponry only gets used during boss fights and side ops for me.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc yeah there is an odd disparity at play where you can have any number of big (and very loud!) weapons but few situations where you can use them without being marked down. Also you can run out of suppressors very quickly in the early stages before developing better ones. To satisfy that itch I like to call in a tank supply drop outside a big base and blow it up in free roam mode. Calling in a support chopper for the task is also fun :) and I do see your point about penetration - it's a trade-off and depends on use and situation so horses for courses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of ammunition & magazine used for a given weapon affects four things:

- damage (not usually any change)
- penetration
- loaded ammo count
- total ammo count

Weapon type also has an impact on these, as do other attachments, and as far as I know, ammo doesn't affect accuracy.

It comes down to common sense - what ammo will give you the best damage & penetration for a given weapon while enabling you to carry enough of it to actually use it?

Sniper rifle ammo (like .308 for instance) in an assault rifle, while giving you great penetration, will quickly be spent when you can only carry 25 rounds of it.

Contrast that with using 7.62mm assault rifle ammunition instead of .308 in a sniper rifle - the penetration more than halves but the damage stays the same, and you can carry hundreds of rounds instead of 25, with bigger magazines. Might be a good choice when going on a long op where you wont be shooting people through cover, or they are unlikely to be armored, or like me you just like the sound of sniper rifles and want to make more noise.

The weapon customisation in MGS5 allows you to do almost anything, but that's not to say that anything it lets you do is a good idea.

In short, using sniper ammo in the G44 will do three things - it will raise penetration, lower your ammo count, and allow you to spray every bullet on full auto. But only once.